# Paradigm for storing user data for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, databases, storage

Disclaimer: I'm not well versed in Game Dev best practices so this may be a trivial question.

I'm developing an iPhone game in which I have to store a user profile containing such information as scores for each level, latest level completed, etc. I've thought of a few ways to store this data but want to do it the "right" way (i.e. how it would be done by professionals) so am I on the right track with any of these methods or is there a better way:

1. Create a User class and serialize it using NSCoding/NSKeyedArchiver/etc. (This seems like overkill)
2. Store all that information with NSUserDefaults.
3. Some other method?